# How can I do this in Django template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am trying to do this in django template:

```
{% for book in books %}
  if book in this library
       print "already in this library"
  else
       print "add to this library"
{% endfor %}
```

there are two libraries `L` and `O`.

but the same book can be in multiple libraries, and i am in Library `L`. the book `b` is in both libraries. thats why my loop is giving both outputs.

```
already in this library
add to this library
```

which is nonesense. How can I repair this logic?

Comment: Your templates MUST avoid logical computations!! Instead, do the required computations in python & have the template simply display them.

Comment: I don't think it is happening due to the same book being in multiple library, but instead because of multiple books being there.

Comment: I think this logic can be addressed in the view. Can you show the relevant view code ?

Comment: A couple of things:
1) That's not valid syntax for the django template tags, it looks like a combination of template tags and python syntax. Please paste the actual template code.
2) Please include the view code that's invoking this template so we can see what your template is parsing.

Comment: @JoshScholl i did this intentionally, my question is not about syntax, but more about logic, so code is pseudo here

Comment: It would be easier to answer if you posted your models... What is the relationship between Book and Library ?

Comment: May I also suggest making your question a little more descriptive for the benefit of others who may be googling similar questions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So there are two scenarios:

- a) book is in some library
- b) book is not in any library

My suggestion would be to do this at the view level and not at the template level:

1. Write a view function that calculates two lists: one of books that are not in a library, and one of books that are in some library.
2. Merge those two arrays into a dictionary (key = book name, value = boolean value indicating whether or not the book is in a library)
3. Send that dictionary to the template

Comment: Depends... If the books have a field (foreign key or whatever) telling which library|ies they belong to and the "current" library is known, there's probably a way simpler solution (like using a template filter)

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers, thats exactly what i have, can you propose your solution?

Comment: @doniyor: depends on your models and your view's context. Please post the relevant code.